# Best way to make sure a Service Process is stopped and its assemblies have been released?

Tags: c#, .net, service

I have a service which can automatically update itself. It does so by downloading and running the installer/updater, which is another executable. That executable stops the service with the `ServiceController` class, makes sure it is stopped using `WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)`, and then copies the relevant files. Those files include the service's main assembly and its dependencies.

Sometimes, the installation works as expected, but sometimes, I get an `IOException` telling me that it cannot access one of the service's assemblies because it is being used by another process (presumably the service which hasn't completely shut down). To remedy this I tried adding a fairly large delay of `1000ms` after the `WaitForStatus` call, before starting to copy the files, but the `IOException` still gets thrown (or not) at random, i.e. sometimes the update is successful and sometimes it isn't.

I then tried adding a call to `Environment.Exit()` at the end of the `ServiceBase.OnStop` implementation of my service, and the update seems to work all the time now. However, I can tell this is not good practice since when I try stopping my service from the SCM, it stops, but gives the error `Service process closed unexpectedly`.

So what is the best way to do what I am trying to do? I could increase the delay, but it seems to me that `1000ms` should be ample time for the service to properly shut down and release its lock on its assemblies. Perhaps I am doing something else incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

I'll write about what I did to solve this problem. I made it so that when a file isn't able to be copied because of that exception, the process enters a loop whereby it waits `1000ms` and tries to copy that file again. It does so 5 times, and if it isn't able to copy the file after 5 times, the installer fails. In practice, from the log information I am receiving, it can take up to 3 seconds from a service process to properly shut down. I think this is the best solution for my problem.